# How to convert HKQuanity to Int in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, swift2, healthkit

This must be really simple, but I can't figure it out. I just need to convert a HKQuanity, which in this case is steps to an Int.

Comment: No, I take a HKQuantitySample and turn it into a HKQuantity : sample[2].quantity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a `HKQuantitySample` object then you can convert the `quantity` property to `Int` using the [`doubleValueForUnit`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKQuantity_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/HKQuantity/doubleValueForUnit:) function like in the following way:

```
let value = Int(sample.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit()))
```

Where `sample` is an `HKQuantitySample`.

Remember you need to cast the samples properly when you pass the optional-binding like this:

```
readFullSample(anyValueYouPassHere) { samples in
     for sample in samples as [HKQuantitySample] {
         let value = Int(sample.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit()))
     }
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: I get this: 2015-10-15 14:05:53.135 Export Health[79376:4267474] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to convert incompatible units: m, count'.....
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: please put your complete query where you get the `HKQuantitySample` object

Comment: func readFullSample(sampleType:HKSampleType , completion: (([HKQuantitySample]) -> Void)) {
        
        let stepsSampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: sampleType,
            predicate: nil,
            limit: 100,
            sortDescriptors: nil)
            { (query, results, error) in
                if let results = results as? [HKQuantitySample] {
                    completion(results)
                }
        }
        
        // Don't forget to execute the Query!
        self.healthKitStore.executeQuery(stepsSampleQuery)
    }

Comment: Same Error readFullSample(HKSampleType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight)!) { (samples) -> Void in
            for sample in samples as [HKQuantitySample] {
                let value = Int(sample.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit()))
            }
        }

Comment: Can you share your project in Github?

Comment: Oh I am so silly, I was getting the Height value, thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry to waste your time

Comment: Don't worry, always is a pleasure help. See you next time

Comment: What about for height and Heart Rate, stuff that aren't simple numbers?